# Convert grayscale png to RGB png image

Tags: python, rgb, grayscale, medical, image-preprocessing

I have a dataset of medical images in grayscale Png format which must be converted to RGB format. Tried many solutions but in vain.

Comment: _"Tried many solutions but in vain"_. Ok, post a couple and we'll start from there.

Comment: What is the point? You would be tripling the storage requirements without adding any information or value. Why do you think you need to convert them?

Comment: This is very unlikely to be a programming problem.   There are any number of off-the-shelf image processing applications (whether UI based or CLI, like `netpbm`) that can perform this function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming problem.

Answer (score 1):

GIMP, Menu image -> Mode -> RGB mode

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just convert the format, the following method will help you:

In python3, using PILLOW and Numpy:

```py
From PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open(path/to/image, 'r').convert('L')
im = np.stack((im,)*3, axis=-1)
im = Image.fromarray(im)
im.save(path/to/save)
```

But if you want to colorize the image, know that colorization is an well-known image translation problem. Even if multiple approachs exist depending on the domain, I don't know any method that colorize any kind of images.

Some ways of doing so is to train a neural network, but for that, you need to have a dataset of B/W and colored images. Here are some approaches:

- Using CNNs and considering the colorization as a regression problem: [Let there be Color!](https://github.com/pvnieo/Deep-Levi)
- Using CNNs and considering the colorization as a classification problem: [Colorful Image Colorization](http://richzhang.github.io/colorization/)
- Using GANs : [cycle-gan](https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix)